# Java - Capture html tags

Tags: java, html, rich-text-editor

I have a Richtexteditor in my web application, I am allowing only Bold, Italics and Underline options for the user.

From a word document, the user can copy another text or paragraph which has Bullets, Alignments, Indentation etc.

Is there any way I can restrict the copying of texts or paragraphs which has 
Bullets, Alignments, Indentation? At the time of submitting the page, can I check the HTML tags which the above using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)

```
String unsafe = "<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
// now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
```

Comment: I am unable to use third party libraries or JARS for this project, so are there any standard feature available? Thanks